# Streaming live webcam to Android smrtphone

Tags: android, streaming, webcam, android-videoview, vlc

So what I want to do is very simple, but I lack experience in streaming methods/softwares. What I want to do is stream my laptops webcam live to a videoView on android. I'm using vlc to stream the webcam using http//:privateIP:8080/stream, with transcoding WMV+WMA.
This is the vlc generated output string:

```
    :sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=asf,dst=:8080/stream} :sout-all :sout-keep
```

my android code is as follows:

```
    package com.example.vlctest;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     VideoView view1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 
     getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

     MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 
     mc.setMediaPlayer(view1); 

     view1.setMediaController(mc); 
     view1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.100:8080/stream")); 
     view1.requestFocus(); 
     view1.start();
}
}
```

Sometimes the app tells me it can't play the video, and sometimes after changing the transcoding the videoview just stays black without doing anything.
If there's a solution for this or a more efficient method please do tell me.

Comment: Your first problem is using WMV. I have a dozen tablets and phones, and not one of them supports Windows media.

Comment: so what's the alternative to wmv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're streaming using WMV format, which is not supported by Android.  You'll need to stream a format that is compatible with Android that is also supported by VLC.

The following settings in VLC will work with an Android device.

Transcode using `H.264` for video and `AAC` for audio. Use `MPEG TS` or `MP4` as the encapuslation format.

These should be available in VLC and in Android 3.0+.

See the following docs for VLC and Android's supported media formats for more info:

http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: I changed the streaming settings as you stated but then vlc gave me the error: VLC could not open the encoder. And the videoView gave a black screen.

Comment: The blank screen in the videoView is because VLC is not opening the encoder.  As for the encoding issue, that's why the gods invented le google. I was able to find this response to that issue in a few seconds: http://www.techyv.com/questions/vlc-could-not-open-enconder.

Comment: the vlc encoding problem is solved :) it only needed to be re-installed. But i'm still facing the black videoview problem, I can see via DU meter on my desktop that vlc is uploading the live video.

Comment: ok so i waited for like 3 mins with black screen, and the video showed up. But it's showing me what the webcam detected 3 mins ago! that's a huge lag. I set the bitrate to 128kbps with 12fps.

Comment: I increased the bitrate to 1600 and got a lag of about 5 secs. It's gd for a start although I'm making this app to control a rc car so 5 sec is still not accepted. But thanks all for ur help :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad that worked.  I'm not sure what OS you're using, but you may also want change the priority of the VLC process to "real time" as well.  That should help with the lag in the streaming / transcoding.  The lag could partly be due to other processes getting priority in the scheduler.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-unix-linux-process-priority/  Same applies for Mac.  I don't know how Windows handles process priority.